# Saving txt file numbers to array (python)

Tags: python, file, import

Code below; works when I call specific positions, but when I print the entire list it seems to loops for ever - stops responding...

```
datafile = r'IntegerArray.txt'

with open(datafile,'r') as f:
    IntegerArray = [int(num) for num in f]

print(IntegerArray[0])
print(IntegerArray[99999])

print(IntegerArray)
```

Comment: Can you give us some example data to work with, such as what the array looks like, or the value of the file IntegerArray.txt?  My thought is that the Array is very large.... So printing the `len(IntegerArray)` may help in understanding the size.... which would make printing it a lengthy process

Comment: its 100000 integers saved in a txt file. The numbers are listed each on its own line in the txt.

Comment: Just checked print(len(IntegerArray)) = 100000, weird, why would it not work when I print the whole thing? Also, I'm trying to run a mergesort on the array. My mergesort work, have tested it on other data, but it falls over on my IntegerArray.

Comment: have you thought that printing 100k elements to a console would take some time?

Comment: I have run your code and it worked fine for me
my .txt file was like this 1\n2\n3\n....  
Which version of python are you running?

Comment: don't think that is the issue, saved it as a string and printed, took like 2 secs...

filename = r"IntegerArray.txt"

f=[]
with open(filename,"r") as filecontent:
    content = filecontent.read()

print(content.read(0))

Comment: I'll reinstall my compiler, maybe some bug... running 3.6.3

Comment: That is a *list* not an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the code is perfect, the issue was with python shell that could not handle the printing of so many integers. The objective was simply to run a Inversion counter. Once I deleted all the print lines in the code it executed within seconds.